# Using Exceptions as Interrupts/Navigation. Is it a bad idea?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am working on a basic windows forms application that have some functions doing 'Heavy' work. Because of this, I use ThreadAbortExceptions together with the help of a Background worker - like so:

```
public class AbortableBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
```

-to cancel the executing functions. Let's call these functions "HeavyFunction()"

But, now that the ThreadAbortException has been caught inside the HeavyFunction(), I somehow need to get back to the "MainForm.cs" class which called the HeavyFunction(). This is to make sure I correctly close other open connections (ex. a Writer) and to show a message to the user. So, I just throw an exception from the HeavyFunction(), and then catch it in MainForm, like so(This is inside the HeavyFunction():

```
catch (ThreadAbortException tae)
            {
                //Deligate abortion upwards.
                SomeWriter.DeleteAndClose();
                throw new ArgumentException("relevant message or identifier for later use here");
                //close and delete
            }
```

The thrown exception is then caught in the "DoWork" function inside MainForm, and handled accordingly.

**My Question** - Is this a bad practice?

I am not that comfortable with Threads and Thread.Abort (Hence the backgroundworker in the first place)

**Sub Question** - What simple elegant solutions are there to bubble responses back up to the form from within a called class?

Comment: Exceptions should not be used for general control flow.

Comment: This is definitely bad practice because `Thread.Abort` is the wrong thing to do 99% of the time.

Comment: @Jon I would say more like 99.9%! Not only that, you can't actually swallow a `ThreadAbortException` so all your doing really is adding *another* exception to the call stack.

Comment: Hehe, thanks guys, had the feeling I was partaking in a big no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a bad practice?

Yes, `ThreadAbortException` in general is a bad practice.

IMO, it will be much better, if MS didn't invent this exception ever, because many people consider `TAE` as a legal way to stop any operation.

> So, I just throw an exception from the HeavyFunction()
>   What simple elegant solutions are there to bubble responses back

You've just re-invented TPL's [`OperationCancelledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.aspx).
Simple and elegant solution is to use TPL and its graceful cancellation pattern:

```
          var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

          Task
            .Factory
            .StartNew(() => 
             { 
                 /* HeavyFunction */ 
                 while (someCondition)
                 {
                    cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    /*  do something */
                 }
             }, cts.Token);
```

If you want to do some actions only when your `HeavyFunction` was cancelled, add a continuation after `StartNew`:

```
.StartNew(/*  */)
.ContinueWith(() => {/* some action */}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps. I will give this a look at & try it. So would TPL's then be the most common practice to use in C# for "class communication"/getting back to the MainForm with a response? Or is there an even more simple design pattern that I can use to achieve the same goal? (The goal being to get a response back to the main form without the form having to wait for the called function to exit/finish)

Comment: @nicovanvuuren what you are talking about is known as cross-thread invocation i.e. you want to notify the UI thread from another thread. It's pretty trivial to do that e.g. `MainForm.Invoke(delegate { /** run on the UI thread **/ });`

Comment: @James. How the heck did I miss that. Think I need to get up and walk around a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @nicovanvuuren: TPL isn't a "class communication" library. It is about running *tasks* (the task here is an abstract concept, that does some work and can finish with one of outcomes - completed, faulted, cancelled). And of course, TPL isn't intended for UI applications only. If you want to tell the creator of the task, that task is finished, than TPL provides you some convenient API (for example, you could wish to display message box, when task is cancelled). But I definitely can't understand, what do you mean with "class communication".

Comment: @Dennis. That clears up the context for me thanks. Yes "class communication" was a bit of a loose term to use. I just meant having the means for the calling class/function to be instantly notified by the called class/function of any changes/interrupts that occurred. Which - as per your description above - is exactly what TPL's would solve for me

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWorker supports cancellation scenario.

The UI thread has to call bw.CancelAsync() while inside DoWork you need to check for bw.CancellationPending property, if it's true you should exit DoWork.

```
private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
{
    bw.CancelAsync();
}
}
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
{
    if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something heavy
    }
}
}
```